Reference Request: Completeness of the space of all Whittaker models(a lemma in JPSS1981)
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$There is a lemma in the proofs of local converse theorem stated as

Suppose $F$ is a non-archimedean local field, $\psi$ is a non-trivial addtive character on $F$. $N_n$ is the subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$ consisting of upper triangular matrices of which the diagonal entities are all $1$. Let $H(g)$ be a smooth $\mathbb{C}$-valued function on $\GL_n(F)$ satisfying
$$
    H(ng)=\psi^{-1}(n)H(g) \text{ for any }n\in N_n \text{ and }g\in \operatorname{GL}_n(F)
  $$and compactly supported modulo $N_n$. Suppose
\begin{equation}
    \int_{N_n\backslash{\operatorname{GL}_n(F)}} H(g)W(g) dg =0
  \end{equation} for all admissible irreducible generic representations $(\pi,V_\pi)$ of $\text{GL}_n(F)$ and all $W\in\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)$. Then $H\equiv 0$.

(The above lemma could be found as lemma 2.1 Chen2006, lemme 2.1 Henniart1993, lemma 2.3 Chai2016, Jacquet–Liu, lemma in (3.2) JS1985).
JS1985 says: "With trivial modifications the proof is word for word the same as that of JPSS1981". So all these references go to lemme 3.5 Jacquet–Piateskii–Shapiro–Shalika1981. But I can not understand its proof.（It's a brief proof in French, so I can't translate properly.）
The content in JPSS1981((3.3)-(3.5)) is as follows.

(3.3)Soit maintenant $\psi$ un caractère additif non trivial de $F$ d’exposant 0. Pour toute suite de nombres complexes non nuis $(x_1,x_2,...,x_r)$, il existe une fonction $W$ et une seule telle que
\begin{align}
&W(ngk)=\theta(n)W(g),\ n\in N_r,\ k\in K_r\tag{1}\\
&W(e)=1 \tag{2}\\
&\int W(gh)\phi(h)dh=\lambda(\phi)W(g)\text{ pour tout }\phi\in H\tag{3}
\end{align}
où $\lambda$ est le morphisme de $H$ dans $\mathbb{C}$ décrit dans (3.2) (cf. Shintani). Nous noterons cette fonction
$$
W(g,x_1,x_2,...,x_r;\psi)\tag{4}
$$
Il résulte de l’unicité que
$$
W(w{^{t}g^{-1}},x_1,x_2,...,x_r;\psi)=W(g,x^{-1}_1,x^{-1}_2,...,x^{-1}_r;\bar{\psi})\tag{5}
$$
De plus si $q^{-s}=x$, alors
$$
W(g,x_1,x_2,...,x_r;\psi)\lvert\operatorname{det}{g}\rvert^s=W(g,x_1x,x_2x,...,x_rx; \psi) \tag{6}
$$
La formule explicite donnée en Shintani montre qu’il existe pour chaque $g\in\GL(r)$ un élément $W(g,X_1,X_2,...,X_r;\psi)$ de $S_r$ dont $W(g,x_1,x_2,...,x_r;\psi)$ soit la spécialisation. On a ainsi défini une fonction sur $\GL(r)$ à valeurs dans $S_r$; d’ailleurs ses valeurs sur un ensemble compact modulo $N_r$ sont dans un sous-espace vectoriel de dimension finie de $S_r$. D’après (3.1), le support de $W(g,X_1,X_2,...,X_r;\psi)$ est
contenu dans l’ensemble des $g$ tels que
$$
\lvert\alpha_i(g)\rvert\leq 1,\text{ pour }1\leq i\leq r-1\tag{7}
$$
Si de plus $\lvert\alpha_r(g)\rvert\leq 1$ alors $W(g,X_1,X_2,...,X_r;\psi)$ est en fait dans $\mathbb{C}[X_1,X_2,...,X_r]$.


(3.4) Nous aurons à considérer des «intégrales» de la forme
$$
 \int_{N_r\backslash{\operatorname{GL}_r(F)}} W(g,X_1,\dotsc,X_r;\psi)\varphi(g)\lvert\det g\rvert^s dg =0\tag{1}\label{479957_3.4_1}
$$
où $\varphi$ est une fonction se transformant à gauche par $\theta_{\bar\psi, r} = \bar\theta_{\psi, r}$. La fonction $\varphi$ sera supposée lisse à droite,
c’est-à-dire invariante à droite par un sous-groupe compact ouvert de $\GL_r$. De plus le support de $\varphi$ sera toujours contenu
dans l’ensemble des $g$ tels que
$$
|\alpha_r(g)|\leq C \tag{2}\label{479957_3.4_2}
$$
où $C$ est une constante non nulle.
L’intégrale est à interpréter comme série formelle
$$
\sum a_nX^n,\ X=q^{-s}\tag{3}\label{479957_3.4_3}
$$
à coefficients dans $S_r$, les coefficients étant donnés par l’intégrale ordinaire
$$
 \int_{N_r\backslash{\operatorname{GL}_r(F)}} W(g,X_1,\dotsc,X_r;\psi)\varphi(g)\mu_n(\det g) dg =0\tag{4}\label{479957_3.4_4}
$$
où $\mu_n$ est la fonction caractéristique de l’ensemble
$$
\{x\in F^{\times}\mid v(x)=n\}\tag{5}\label{479957_3.4_5}
$$
dans $F^{\times}$.
Il est clair que les conditions (3.3)(7), (3.4)\eqref{479957_3.4_2} et $v(\det g)=n$
impliquent que $g$ est dans un ensemble compact mod $N_r$:
la fonction à intégrer dans \eqref{479957_3.4_4} est donc à support compact mod $N_r$ et l’intégrale a bien un sens.
De plus notons que les relations (3.3)(7) et (3.4)\eqref{479957_3.4_2} entraînent $v(\det g)\geq m$, où $m$
est un entier qui dépend de $C$.
Il en résulte que dans la série \eqref{479957_3.4_3} on a $a_n=0$ pour $n<m$.


(3.5)  Lemme. Gardons les hypothèses de (3.4) mais supposons de plus que $\varphi$
soit invariante à droite par $K_r$. Alors la relation
$$
 \int_{N_r\backslash{\operatorname{GL}_r(F)}} W(g,X_1,\dotsc,X_r;\psi)\varphi(g)\lvert\det(g)\rvert^s dg =0
$$
entraine $\varphi = 0$.


Démonstration. If suffit de démontrer le lemme lorsque $\phi$ a un support compact modulo $N_r$.
L’hypothèse du lemme s’écrit alors :
$$
 \int_{N_r\backslash{\operatorname{GL}_r(F)}} W(g,X_1,\dotsc,X_r;\psi)\varphi(g) dg =0\tag{1}\label{479957_3.5_1}
$$
pour tout $(X_1,\dotsc,X_r)$.
Montrons que cela entraine $\varphi=0$. Pour cela considérons la représentation $\pi$ de $\GL_r$ induite,
au sens de Mackey, par le caractère (de module 1) $\theta{\bar\psi, r}$.
Décomposons la en somme continue de représentations irréductibles:
$$
\pi=\int\pi_xd\mu(x).
$$
Soit $V$ l’ensemble des fonctions lisses à droite et support compact modulo $N_r$
dans l’espace de la représentation $\pi$.
Comme $V$ a une base linéaire dénombrable, il existe, pour presque tout $x$,
une application linéaire $A_x$ de $V$ dans l’espace de la représentation $\pi_x$ telle que
$$
\langle\varphi_1,\varphi_2\rangle=\int\langle A_x\varphi_1,A_x\varphi_2\rangle\mu(x),\ \varphi_1,\varphi_2\in V.\tag{2}\label{479957_3.5_2}
$$
De plus, pour presque tout $x$, on a
$$
A_x\pi(g)\varphi=\pi_x(g)A_x\varphi,\ g\in \GL_r,\ \varphi\in V.
$$
Soit maintenant $\varphi_0$ un élément de $V$ invariant sous $K_r$.
Alors $A_x\varphi_0=0$ à moins que $\pi_x$ ait un vecteur $v_x\neq 0$ invariant sous $K_r$.
Supposons qu’il en soit ainsi;
alors il existe une fonction $W$ et une seule se transformant à gauche par $\theta_{\psi, r}$, telle que, pour tout $\varphi\in V$,
$$
\langle A_x\varphi,v_x\rangle=\int_{N_r\backslash{\operatorname{GL}_r(F)}}\varphi(g)W(g)dg.
$$
Comme $v_x$ est $K_r$-invariant la fonction $W$ est $K_r$-invariant à droite.
De plus $v_x$ doit être un vecteur propre pour l’algèbre $H_r$.
Il en est donc de même de la fonction $W$.
Par conséquent cette fonction est un multiple d’une fonction $W(g,X_1,\dotsc,X_r;\psi)$. Si $\varphi_0$ satisfait \eqref{479957_3.5_1}
alors $\langle A_x\varphi_0,v_x\rangle=0$ ou encore $A_x\varphi_0 = 0$.
Ainsi $A_x\varphi_0=0$ pour presque tout $x$.
D’après \eqref{479957_3.5_2} on a $\varphi_0=0$. Q.E.D.

Questions:

In JPSS1981, they use "continuous decomposition of $\pi$ into irreducible representations $\pi_x$ in the sense of Mackey". I take it as some kind of direct integral decomposition as in Theorem 1.G.8. Is this understanding correct? Mackey’s lecture is hard to understand for me. Is there other reference?
In JPSS1981, "soit $V$ l'ensemble des fonctions lisses a droite et support compact modulo $N_r$." What does it mean for a function to be "smooth on the right"？How to understand $V$?
I also can not understand the last part of argument in JPSS1981. What is the use of $\varphi_0$?
I guess there is some kind of "multiplicity one" involved in the proof, but I do not know where.



They are probably using "smooth on the right" in the sense of uniform smoothness: there is an open subgroup $U$ such that $f(g u) = f(g)$ for all $g \in G$ and $u \in U$. \ Could you summarise the statement and proof of the JPSS result, for those that don't have easy access?  (I can't tell if the blockquoted statement is the JPSS result, or from one of the other references.)


I see that you say that you cannot translate from French.  Could you post the proof in French, as well as the statement of the lemma?

@LSpice Thanks for the comment. It makes sense since in the previous part of JPSS1981 it requires a function on $GL_n$ to be invariant under right translation of some compact subgroup of maximal compact subgroup of $GL_n$.

@LSpice OK, I'll post the related content in french.

Re, great, thanks.  I made some tweaks to the OCR, and think it is now correct.  If you agree, then you can delete the images.  1. I think so, and I don't know.  3. I believe that, at the beginning of the proof, they mean to write $\varphi_0$ for the putative element of the kernel, and leave $\varphi$ for a general element of $V$. 4. The statement about $W$ is the uniqueness of the Whittaker functional of a generic representation.
